# Hardware RAID 1 is losing data and Windows is "rediscovering" the drive

Tags: windows-7, raid, raid-1

Two mornings have passed by now where I wake up and check my email only to find my Windows computer "discovering" my hardware RAID 1 drive. It pulls up the "Autoplay" options as if it was just plugged in. The strange part is my RAID 1 consists of two HDD's plugged into my motherboard over SATA. I have no clue what this means, but I can at least say that the two times this has happened was when I first interacted with the computer in the morning (About 4 days between occurrences). When this does happen, **recent writes to my RAID are completely gone**. I am losing data in a RAID 1....

Computer information:

- My computer and hard drives do not go to sleep ever:

[image]

- Here is my RAID drive (F) shown in the Computer Management view:

[image]

- I am running a hardware RAID on my Gigabyte GA-990XA-UD3 motherboard

Any ideas on how I can diagnose this? I am fearing that one day my RAID 1 will explode and I will lose all my data. Any ideas on the problem? Any ideas on what will happen if this eventually gets worse? Is there a chance that I will lose all data if the RAID controller dies?

Comment: Unrelatyed to an answer, but are you sure it is hardware RAID? It looks like SB950 is software RAID. (Or to be more precise, fake RAID just like the Intel chipsets do. No real dedicated RAID hardware, only support in the firmware (UEFI or BIOS) and all the work done in drivers. This is relevant as to where to look for the problem. With HW RAID the RAID card should present only one drive. Problems should be handled by the RAID card. FOr software RAID it is handled by windows.

Comment: Well I will just explain how I installed it. I thought it was a hardware RAID, but you may be right. I reinstalled Windows and at the beginning installed the RAID drivers that I downloaded from Gigabyte's website. I set up the array in a new BIOS utility that was accessible right after the bios boot up screen. Windows only ever sees one drive (my F drive). Is this considered hardware or software RAID?

Comment: Also updated my post. I am running the mirroring RAID, not the striping RAID. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ugh. Loosing data to a mirror sounds more serious. Is there anything in the log files ([start] [run] `eventvwr.msc`) ?

Comment: A little background about RAID. In the past CPUs were relative slow compared to disk IO. Creating a RAID array consumed significant CPU cycles, which where then not available for other tasks. One solution for this was a dedicated card with its own CPU (or custom ASIC) to do these calculations. This was mostly done for RAID 5 and similar. (RAID 0 and RAID 1 are trivial calculations). Back then you either used software RAID (the OS/driver did it for you) or hardware RAID (multiple drives connected to on plugin card, that card presented one [fake, larger] drive.

Comment: In the last decade software RAID has taken advantage of the much faster modern CPU's and often gained support in the motherboard firmware (e.g in BIOS). All the calculations are still done by the OS/driver. It is merely a nice tool to help to set up the software RAID and it makes it easier to boot from an array.

Both AMD and Intel (and other third parties) have this fake RAID in their options, next to normal software RAID and normal HW RAID. And performanace wise there is nothing wrong with it. It just changes to focus on where to debug your problem.

Comment: Ok the logs are relatively scarce (surprisingly), and there isn't a peep about anything going on with my drives. I actually am open to doing a Windows RAID using the Disk Management approach. Does this sound like a reasonable approach to moving away from my problem? Also, can I simply unplug one of my drives and go on with my day safely (assuming my RAID controller is the problem)?

Comment: Your [motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3894#sp) seems to have RAID support via both AMD950 southbridge and the Marver SATA ports. To which of these is your array connected? If it is the AMD connector, do you have an AMD SATA RAID utility? (ditto for the Marvel  ports).